# node ws is not connecting

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am following a tutorial on WebRTC and I am having a problem with the var declaration of the client.js file.

i installed node, ws and wscat to test the websocket connection.

but when i do this to test the connection:  wscat -c ws://echo.websocket.org 
i get this error:  unexpected server response (404)

so when i run my index.html with this code:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');
var name = '';
var loginInput = document.querySelector('#loginInput');
var loginbtn = document.querySelector('#loginbtn');
var othrUsernameInput = document.querySelector('#othrUsernameInput');
var connectToOtherUsernameBtn = document.querySelector('#connectToOtherUsernameBtn');
var connectedUser, myConnection;
```

i get an error on line#1 saying that: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

any idea how to fix this problem? i have been trying to fix this error for a while now and i cant move forward if i cant make this work.

Comment: Is the 8080/9090 a typo?

Comment: when i start the server, it is on 8080. but the example is supposed to be on 9090. which confused me greatly.